# Process inside process inside process

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm working on this project to extract text from images.
My application works perfectly well but it takes 3 minutes to run .
I managed to parallel my code with multiprocessing library of python and I'm now doing 2 minutes.However ,it can get a lot better:

I'm running 2 functions in parallel(inside each function I extract 8 fields of text and then for each text I do 5 calls of  function of text processing)

Can anyone give an example on how to do process inside process inside process?any simple example ?
[image]

Comment: See [Parallel MapReduce in Python in Ten Minutes](https://mikecvet.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/parallel-mapreduce-in-python/) and [Implementing MapReduce with multiprocessing](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/mapreduce.html)

Comment: Why would you need a tree of processes? Managing everything from a single process is probably easier. Unlike threads, you don't have _cheap_ automatic data sharing. I'd share image data with either files or shared memory. And indeed, with a CPU-bound task, you don't want more processes than you have cores, _and_ your working set should fit into the L3 cache; with large images, the cache may be filled with fewer than 8 processes. I'd just run 8 parallel red processes, then 8 parallel green processes. In general, I'd send tasks over a queue to a process pool. The docs have an intro.